# Was the bowl in "—We Also Walk Dogs" stolen?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein

In Heinlein's *[—We Also Walk Dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%94We_Also_Walk_Dogs)* there is a bowl from the British museum that is used to induce a genius to create antigravity. At one point, he asks if the bowl is stolen property and the General Services people say no.

> O’Neil eyed him. ‘It’s stolen property.’
>
> ‘You’re mistaken. Nor will you find anyone to take an interest in such
> a charge. Now about this job—’

But well...was it?  And how did they get it out of the museum?

Comment: Maybe they were lying?

Comment: Gs has a lot of money - including the income from a brand new antigravity device. They bought it or bribed folks to get it

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Comment: @Andrew:  General Services needed the "Flower" to get the physicist to develop the antigravity device.  They needed it before they had the device.  They didn't pay any bribes to get the Flower out of money made from the device.

Comment: I'm figuring they could bribe or buy with their current large stacks of cash secure in the knowledge they'll get more from antigravity soon

Comment: @Andrew you seem to be forgetting that the whole project with antigravity was only done in support of a high-stakes secret request to General Services, with a value of hundreds of billions of credit to the future of the planet, and there would be absolutely no worry about large price tags in the course of that work.

Comment: @Wildcard Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems not to have been stolen, but to have been purchased by permission of the person in the planetary government who had the authority to allow it—but done with absolutely no publicity of any sort, especially to avoid the attention of British Parliament who would have objected to the release of the piece.  And it was done in return for a lot of money, and attention from the right blonde.

> "It will take the Government to get anything loose from the British Museum."
>
> ...  "You remember the treaty under which Great Britain entered the planetary confederation?  ...  It comes to this: I doubt if the planetary government can touch anything that belongs to the Museum without asking the British Parliament.
>
> "Why not?  Treaty or no treaty, the planetary government is sovereign.  That was established in the Brazilian incident."
>
> "Yeah, sure.  But it could cause questions to be asked in the House of Commons and that would lead to the one thing Beaumont wants to avoid at all costs—publicity.  ...  Sance and I had better slide over to England and find out just how tight they have the 'Flower of Forgetfulness' nailed down—and who does the nailing and what his weaknesses are."

Then later:

> "We located the guy.  His weakness is blondes.  ...  This will have to be a left-handed job.  In the ordinary way, it would take an earthquake to get anything out of that tomb.  ...  I won't get you in trouble.  But it will be expensive."

And finally:

> "I wasn't the blonde he was weak for," she explained, "but I found the one he was interested in.  ...  Sance is having a facsimile integrated.  With luck, we'll see you tomorrow."

Comment: Yes, artistically speaking a direct lie would not be in character.  This seems much more in the spirit of the creativity of GS as an org also.

Comment: Basically, I think they got planetary government permission to buy it...or were given it...but then bribed a guard or museum director to "steal" it, so there was no publicity.  This would also support the nobody would take an interest in the charge

Comment: If they could "re-integrate" a copy to put in the Museum, why didn't they just give the scientist the copy?

Comment: @FlaStorm32 that's a whole separate question and it's answered very directly in the story.  There are two parts to that: (1) They already offered O'Neil the idea of a copy and he said absolutely no way.  (2) Read the story to understand the emotional impact of the original piece of artwork.  In my view, that's the actual crux of the entire story, and all the stuff about politics and anti-gravity is just enjoyable surrounding circumstances to that real central punch.

Comment: I would suggest eminent domain and sealed court orders, along with a bribe to a security guard.  All except the bribe would be legal.  OTOH, for all we know the planetary governments already officially owns it, and wouldn’t need to even go to court, and all of this was (as quoted above) just to avoid the publicity

Answer (score 6):

I've always interpreted the passages quoted in [the answer by Wildcard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/286235/44649) to mean that they found the guy responsible for the security of "The Flower of Forgetfulness" and convinced him (by application of female charms) to steal the real "Flower of Forgetfulness" and put a copy ("we're having a facsimile integrated") in its place.  No one in the British government is aware of the swap, and the only person in the museum  who does know that there's now a fake in place won't talk.

They didn't physically break in and swipe it, but they certainly don't have permission of the British government and the museum operators.  They all believe that "The Flower of Forgetfulness" is still there - and everyone can see it still on display.

This passage shows that the folks at General Services certainly don't have the "Flower" legally:

> They showed up the next day, apparently empty handed. ‘Well?’ said Clare, ‘well?’
>
> ‘Seal the place up, Jay,’ suggested Francis. ‘Then we’ll talk.’ Clare flipped a switch controlling an interference shield which rendered his office somewhat more private than a coffin. ‘How about it?’ he demanded. ‘Did you get it?’
>
> ‘Show it to him, Grace.’
>
> Grace turned her back, fumbled at her clothing for a moment, then turned around and placed it gently on the Chief’s desk.

They've smuggled it in, hidden in Grace's clothing.  That's not how you transport priceless antiques that you are legally in posession of.

Comment: Yes, this is possible too.  However, this would make O'Neil's statement accurate that it's stolen property, and make the response "You're mistaken" into a lie.  They definitely don't have permission from the British government (hence the secrecy), but it's not impossible they have permission from some official within the *planetary* government.

Comment: @Wildcard:  The folks at General Services have stolen a priceless antique.  A lie at that point is nothing for them to worry about.  They stole it and hid the fact so well that no one in the British government or the museum would even consider that it was stolen.

Comment: I agree with you this is the most plausible explanation, for sure.  But since truth is often stranger than fiction, and since reality would often be considered ridiculously implausible were it fictional—I like to infer whatever explanation into fiction that I enjoy best.  :)